# Why does the state not get updated with the new mutation (in my case, a new post )?

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

My getters are working perfectly and display the hardcoded states data. But when i use actions and mutations to add new post, the new post is not displayed.

I am using the latest version of Vue and Vuex. The data i want to update is taken from user in a create component and should be displayed in a lists component.

```
/modules/lists_data

const actions = {
 createNew ({commit}, payload) {
    const newItem = {
        title: payload.title,
        location: payload.location,
        imageUrl: payload.imageUrl,
        description: payload.description,
        date: payload.date,
        id: 'skwnkqnclqinq'
    };
    commit('addNew',newItem);
}
};

const mutations = {
addNew: (state,payload) => state.loadedLists.push(payload)

};

/components/create
this is the script

import { mapActions } from 'vuex' 

export default {
data() {
    return {
        title: '',
        location: '',
        imageUrl: '',
        description: '',
        inputRules: [
            v => v.length >=3 || 'Minimum length is 3 characters'
        ]
    }
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions(['createNew']),
    onCreateNew(){
        if(this.$refs.form.validate()){
            const newItem = {
                title: this.title,
                location: this.location,
                imageUrl: this.imageUrl,
                description: this.description,
                date: new Date(), 
            }
            this.$store.dispatch('createNew',newItem)


        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Is your `createNew` is inside `module`? can you please paste full code here or a plunker would be even better?

Comment: Check vue-devtools to see if there are any errors and or if the action and mutation fired. If you're not using vue-devtools, read about it [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools)

Comment: Code looks good so far, it seems you need to test/provide more info on what exactly isn't working (or even better a full example on codesandbox).